# saving data into a Mongo database

Tags: c#, mongodb, repository

I want to insert customers into my mongodb. I have a Customer class and an Address value object. currently it doesn't save the address of a customer unless I put the attribute BsonElement in Address's properties.

I wouldn't like to use this "BsonElement" attribute my "domain" are there any other options ?

I thought about creating a DTO, but I would like something easier.

here is my code:

Customer class:

```
public class Customer : Entity<Customer>
{
    public Customer(string firstName, string lastName, string phoneNumber, Address address, IUser user)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Address = address;
        User = user;
        PhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

    }
    public string FirstName { get; protected set; }

    public string LastName { get; protected set; }

    public Address Address { get; protected set; }

    public PhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; protected set; }

    public IUser User { get; protected set; }

    public bool ChangeName(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        if (firstName == this.FirstName &&
            lastName == this.LastName)
        {
            return false;
        }

        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;

        Validations.Update("FirstName", this);
        Validations.Update("LastName", this);

        AddEvent(new CustomerNameChanged(Id, firstName, lastName));

        return true;
    }

    public bool ChangeAddress(Address address)
    {
        if (Address == address)
        {
            return false;
        }

        this.Address = address;

        Validations.Update("Address", this);

        AddEvent(new CustomerAddressChanged(Id, Address));

        return false;
    }

    public bool ChangePhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
    {
        var newPhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        if (newPhoneNumber == PhoneNumber)
        {
            return false;
        }

        this.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;

        AddEvent(new CustomerPhoneChanged(Id, PhoneNumber.Number));

        return true;
    }

}
```

Address Class:

```
public class Address : ValueObject<Address>
{
    public Address(string addressLine1, string addressLine2, string city, string state, string zipCode)
    {
        AddressLine1 = addressLine1;
        AddressLine2 = addressLine2;
        City = city;
        State = state;
        ZipCode = zipCode;
    }


    public string AddressLine1 { get; }

    public string AddressLine2 { get; }

    public string City { get; }

    public string State { get; }

    public string ZipCode { get; }

    public override bool Equals(ValueObject<Address> other)
    {
        var address = other as Address;
        return address != null &&
               AddressLine1 == address.AddressLine1 &&
               AddressLine2 == address.AddressLine2 &&
               City == address.City &&
               State == address.State;
    }

}
```

Insert method:

```
public void Insert(Customer customer)
{
        _mongoDatabase
            .GetCollection<Customer>("Customers")      
            .InsertOne(customer);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's not saving? Or not being loaded? You might look into `BsonClassMap` and `ConventionRegistry` if you want to customize your serialization more.

Comment: thanks for help me. I will follow this tutorial http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/serialization/

Comment: I guess it will solve my problem

Comment: I think it's strange that address wouldn't be saved with your model as above. Mongo doesn't require `BsonElement` or a pre-defined class map. I wonder if it is being saved, but not loaded because of the protected properties.

Comment: It is not saving, I've checked in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to register a map for my customer and address.

Customer map registration:

```
 BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Customer>(m =>
        {
            m.MapField(x => x.FirstName);
            m.MapField(x => x.LastName);
            m.MapField(x => x.LastName);
            m.MapField(x => x.PhoneNumber);
            m.MapField(x => x.Address);
            m.MapField(x => x.User);
        });
```

Address map registration:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Address>(m =>
        {
            m.MapField(x => x.AddressLine1);
            m.MapField(x => x.AddressLine2);
            m.MapField(x => x.City);
            m.MapField(x => x.State);
            m.MapField(x => x.ZipCode);
        });
```

I call all maps on my Startup.cs, It worked.